# passing an instance of the class Limits

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

There is a [class Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) that allows to keep track of the governor limits. I need to capture 6 of the governor details of this class, that is why I need to pass an instance of the class Limits to a method.

### I am trying to achieve the following:

```
public void logAppPerformance(Limits li) {
    Database.insert(new InvoicingTaskLog__c(QueriesIssued__c = li.getQueries(), DmlRowsRetrieved__c = li.getDmlRows(), DMLStatementsIssued__c = li.getDmlStatements(), HeapSize__c = li.getHeapSize()), false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods from [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) class are static.

> **getDMLRows()**
>
> Returns the number of records that have been processed
>   with any statement that counts against DML limits, such as DML
>   statements, the Database.emptyRecycleBin method, and other methods.
>
> **Signature**
>
> public static Integer getDMLRows()
>
> Return Value
>
> **Type: Integer**

You don't need to pass instance of it. Simply call `Limits.getDmlRows()` etc.

```
public void logAppPerformance() {
    Database.insert(new InvoicingTaskLog__c(QueriesIssued__c = Limits.getQueries(), DmlRowsRetrieved__c = Limits.getDmlRows(), DMLStatementsIssued__c = Limits.getDmlStatements(), HeapSize__c = Limits.getHeapSize()), false);
}
```